# Gulp: How to delete a folder?

Tags: gulp

I use the `del` package to delete a folder:

```
gulp.task('clean', function(){
    return del('dist/**/*', {force:true});
});
```

...But is there any easy way to delete the `dist` folder and all of its contents if it contains many subdirectories [recursively]?

Ps: I don't want to do it this way: `dist/**/**/**/**/**/**/...`, when there are many subdirectories.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/robrich/gulp-rimraf ?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

your code should look like this:

```
gulp.task('clean', function(){
     return del('dist/**', {force:true});
});
```

according to the npm del docs "**" deletes all the subdirectories of dist (ps: don't delete dist folder):

"The glob pattern ****** matches all children and the parent."

[reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del)

Comment: Thanks. Do you think is there any difference between `dist/**` and `dist/**/*`? Since `**` matches '/' and its children and `*` matches any characters except `/`, I think they're same. What do you think?

Answer (score 9):

According to the documentation :
The glob pattern ** matches all children and the parent.
You have to explicitly ignore the parent directories too

```
gulp.task('clean', function(){
     return del(['dist/**', '!dist'], {force:true});
});
```

More info available here : [del documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del#beware)

Answer (score 6):

Imports:

```
const { src, dest, series, parallel } = require('gulp');
const del = require('del');
```

In one line:

```
function clean(cb) {
  del(['./dist/'], cb());
}
```

Or, In two lines:

```
function clean(cb) {
  del(['./dist/']);
  cb();
}
```

Finally:

```
exports.default = series(clean, parallel(process1, process2));
```