# Gulp is not overwriting JS files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, copy, task

I have a problem when I try to overwrite a file with gulp. To make you understand my problem here's an example of what I am trying to do:
My project file path:

```
- Project
 |- clients
   |- clientBase
     |- JS
       |- jsexample.js
       |- jsexample2.js
     |- CSS
     |- HTML
   |- client1
     |- JS
       |- jsexample2.js
 |-dist
```

1. Copy the base source to `dist`.
2. Copy the custom client source and overwrite what's in the dist folder.

#### What am I doing

```
const args = require('yargs').argv;
const src = {
  base: './Project/clients/clientBase',
  client: `./Project/clients/${args.client}`,
};
const dist = './Project/dist';
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('copy:base', function(){
  return gulp
    .src(`${src.base}/**/*`)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dist))
});

gulp.task('copy:client', function(){
  return gulp
    .src(`${src.client}/**/*`)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dist))
});

gulp.task('copy', function(){
  if (args.client) {
    runSequence('copy:base', 'copy:client');
  } else {
    runSequence('copy:base');
  }
});
```

#### The actual problem

The problem is that the dist files are not being overwritten by the `copy:client` task.

#### What I've checked already

I've checked the file path and the content inside the files. The argument `client` is being passed to, so this task is being executed.

Comment: Have you tried deleting dist folder once before next copy? did that work?

Comment: Hello @palaѕн, yes, I tried, the but the problem still occurs.

Comment: Maybe you can add a new task for it like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36142799/1823841)

Comment: Well, even trying to hard delete the files inside the dist folder, the (copy:base) will copy the entire base client files. So, when the (copy:client) is executed, there's already the base files, because these are run in sequence.

Comment: I tested your code.  There is nothing wrong with what you showed.  But, edit your question to show your src object.  And how you get the args.client value.

Comment: I've updated the issue and now you can see all the variables used in the snippet.

Comment: I am using "gulp copy --client=client1" or "gulp copy --client client1" (without the quotes) and it is working perfectly.

Comment: I can tell you this worked in the previous versions of my project. But, somehow, it stopped working with a merge with the `dev` branch. But the files that contain this logic were not edited. They remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I noticed that in my task sequence chain in the `default task`, there was another task copying again the base code, without any logging.

Comment: You should probably delete this question then - the code you did show was fine and code you didn't show was the problem.  Sigh...

Answer (score 0):

dist needs to be quoted:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
```

You may also need to change the path, depending on where you're running gulp from

Comment: Dist is actually a variable. It stores the dist location, and these tasks run without errors. The problem is that the last task that is run (`copy:client`), is not overwriting the files in the dist folder.

Comment: Ah, sorry - that wasn't clear.  In that case, am I right in thinking that you want the client1/jsexample2.js file to overwrite the base/jsexample2.js copied in the previous step?  And that (copy:base) does copy the files successfully?

Comment: Yes, that's correct @katsho. Yes, after this task (copy:base) is complete, the base client is correctly copied to the dist folder.

Comment: hmm, in that case I can't see anything wrong with what your doing - base & client should run in sequence, not parallel, so that should work.  You could try .pipe(gulp.dest('dist', {overwrite:true})) although that should be the default. After that it may be an OS thing - is the original write keeping a handle to the copied base js2example.js file  just long enough to prevent the overwrite ?

Comment: The main object is to overwrite the base source with the client source. Even forcing the `overwrite: true` in the pipe options, it's not being overwritten.